# How to set the multiple same name query in javascript ajax

Tags: javascript, python

I have python api which can get the multiple data in same query such as.

`createdata?ob=120&st=cool&st=warm`

It can get `st` as `["cool","warm"]` in python.

```
st = request.query_params.getlist("st")

print(st) #["cool","warm"] get the data as array.
```

Now I want to do the same thing  from `ajax`

I try this

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "defapp/createdata",
      method: "GET",
      data: {"ob":130,"st":"warm","st":"cool"},
      contentType: "application/json",
```

and this.

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "defapp/createdata",
      method: "GET",
      data: {"ob":130,"st":["warm","cool"]},
      contentType: "application/json",
```

However former one get  `["cool"]` as `st`

later one get `[]` as `st`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's don't work,because you api not recive a `data body`,but it recive a params value.
You can changed to these below.

```js
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "defapp/createdata?ob=120&st=cool&st=warm",
      method: "GET",
      data: {},
      contentType: "application/json",
```

I hope is can work in your case.

Comment: AH, I understood!!! `data body` and `param in url` is defferent. Thank you very much